# How to escape a special character that is hidden inside variable in unix shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I'm using a bash shell script to delete certain files in directory using the below script

```
#!/bin/bash
path=$1
for filename in $path/*; do
    if [ -d "$filename" ]; then
        echo $filename
        rm $filename/*statssys*
    fi
done
```

In other words, it is looping one through all directories one level deep inside my specified path and removing any files that have `statssys` in the name. The problem is that the file paths retrieved in `$filename` contain numerical endings like `file_path[8]` or `file_path[9]`. The square brackets have to be escaped before the `rm` command works which I do not know how to do as they are hidden inside the $filename variable.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Change all references of `$filename` to `"$filename"`. For example, `rm "$filename"/*statssys*`.

Comment: See [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

Comment: Thanks @FedonKadifeli - that solved it! I had tried using double quotes before but I had put it around the whole statement instead of just the variable name which didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bash scripts there are many pitfalls that a casual programmer may fall into.

One rule is to double quote every parameter expansion which is your main problem. Some other rules include *avoid `echo` to output arbitrary data* and *use `--` to separate options from other arguments* to guard against arguments that happen to start with `-` but should not be taken as options.

In your example, you can change your script to something like:

```
#!/bin/bash --
path="$1"
for filename in "$path"/*; do
    if [ -d "$filename" ]; then
        printf '%s\n' "$filename"
        rm -- "$filename"/*statssys*
    fi
done
```

For more detailed explanation I strongly advise you to read [Bash Pitfalls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls).